# What difference does it make to use "%1d" instead of "%d" only in scanf statement?

Tags: c

https://www.codechef.com/problems/LCOLLIS

I was solving the above problem on codechef and I wrote the below code for it but it gave me runtime error (SIGSEVG).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int t, n, m;
scanf("%d", &t);

while(t--)
{
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    int a[10][10], i, j, sum, ans;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }

    ans = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(a[j][i] == 1)
                sum++;
        }


        if(sum > 1)
            ans = ans + ( sum * (sum - 1) ) / 2;
    }

    printf("%d\n", ans);
}

return 0;
}
```

And I saw one of the solutions that was exactly same as mine just with a little difference and it was accepted. The code is the following :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int t, n, m;
scanf("%d", &t);

while(t--)
{
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    int a[10][10], i, j, sum, ans;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
            scanf("%1d", &a[i][j]); // SEE RIGHT HERE ITS JUST A 1 BEFORE d
    }

    ans = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(a[j][i] == 1)
                sum++;
        }


        if(sum > 1)
            ans = ans + ( sum * (sum - 1) ) / 2;
    }

    printf("%d\n", ans);
}

return 0;
}
```

Now I couldn't understand how that 1 makes all the difference.
Please someone help me out.

Comment: `%d` reads an `int` while `%1d` reads a single digit

Comment: Please read the man page. Please do effort to search the man page in google, too.

Comment: Although it gives the wrong answer, I cannot see why it would give a SIGSEGV unless `n` or `m` is greater than 10.

Answer (score 1):

Without the width specifier, `scanf()` reads all the digits, rather than stopping after a single one. The following `scanf()`s for the same row will fail, leaving undefined/garbage data in the matrix.

So for the first row from the linked page:

```
111
```

That will be treated as the integer 111, followed by nothing, rather than three ones. This is devious from the CodeChef side, of course. :)

It's super overkill to use `scanf()` to just read single characters, you could do something simpler.

Also, if you do use `scanf()`, *always* check its return value: it's I/O and it *can fail*.

Answer (score 0):

The 1 in `"%1d"` is the *width* limit.  It is the maximum number of *characters* (not only digits), after leading white-space that are scanned.

`"%d"` is not limited as to the maximum number of characters it will scan.

```
int main() {
  int i;
  i = 42; sscanf("  123", "%1d", &i); printf("%d\n", i);
  i = 42; sscanf("123", "%1d", &i); printf("%d\n", i);
  i = 42; sscanf("-123", "%1d", &i); printf("%d\n", i);
  i = 42; sscanf("+123", "%1d", &i); printf("%d\n", i);
  i = 42; sscanf("  -123", "%1d", &i); printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Output

```
1
1
42  // Nothing saved into `i`
42  //       "
42  //       "
```

Answer (score 0):

So, let's say I want to scan a text file and that file contains a matrix of binary digit without any space between them. The conversion specification %d have no extra field (field width and precision fields) defined. While scanning, %d looks for a white space to determine the ending of an integer.

But in our case we have defined a binary matrix without any space thus, the program will throw a garbage value. What we can do is we can define field width 1 in %d, such as %1d. These will not add any extra space while printing output but that way scanf now knows that each integer is a digit with an extra empty field (in our case a space). Now even you don't put space between two digits it will scan it as separate digits.

For example, 1001010 will be scanned as different digit as 1 and 0 separately rather than scanning 1001010 as an entire digit. Here is a simple code example.

```
int main()
    {
        FILE *ptr;

        int i,j,count_0=0,count_1=0;
        int a[row][col];

        ptr=fopen("bin.txt","r");

        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                fscanf(ptr,"%1d",&a[i][j]);

            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
           for(j=0;j<3;j++)
           {
              printf("%1d",a[i][j]);
           }
           printf("\n");
        }

     return 0;
    }
```